# How could I create this huge knotted blanket?

Tags: modeling, texturing, modifiers, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation

I am modelling an interior scene and I need to create a blanket. Thing is, its made up of lots of small knots, and though usually I'd just use a texture, it seems really easy to tell that its not actual geometry.

[image]

I have tried using a displacement map but it ends up looking more like a plane with weird texturing then my actual goal. I have also tried creating a knot, then setting a plane as a rigid body, then setting the knot as a collision object, and running the animation. It simply just contours around it but in not high enough detail, and I cannot afford too many subdivisions. I'm honestly not sure what else to try..Can't even seem to find many textures like this one, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You may want to try theh fabric-o-matic plugin https://www.blendernation.com/2019/12/03/fabric-o-matic-an-addon-for-procedural-weaving-free-beta/

Comment: Also here's a tutorial on how to do it https://youtu.be/6zaAA0QqVPE

Comment: @RickT I will check it out thanks..But it's not used in the video? only thing i see is him using the poliigon material converter...

Comment: Probably this tutorial could help to do the material https://youtu.be/GBIXU9BlyXg?t=103

Comment: Will using adaptive sampling subdivision surface, a better quality displacement wool/knitted yarn texture work? Adaptive subdivision won't make your PC crash. Trust me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using a displacement map. If you meant the “looking like a plane with weird texturing” is a bump, you should change the **surface displacement** setting on the material tab. Make sure you changed it to displacement (displacement ONLY or displacement and bump):

[image: displacement setting]

Once you’re done, the displacement should work properly. If you noticed it looks like a wavy plane, make sure you have enough vertices to displace. Of course we’re not going to add a subdivision surface with high level, we’re going to enable the **adaptive subdivision**. This allows you to add geometries based on what you need. I recommend using the *simple* setting instead of Catmull-clark so it doesn’t change the mesh shape.
**Note**: If you can’t find the setting on the subdivision surface modifier, switch the setting from **supported** to **experimental** feature on the engine setting.
You could find some texture (or disp. map) on websites like Poliigon, Pinterest, and many other.
I recently made a Christmas scene with a scarf, and here’s how it looks like (sorry for bad quality)

[image: scarf preview]

Remember to use displacement map on the displacement node. You can choose any base color :)

Comment: Turns out I had it set to bump only..Its always the small details that get me haha

Answer (score 3):

Looking up closely to such a blanket:
[image]

You can see a knot structure (duhhh):
[image]

using array modifier we can recreate the complete blanket from this.
[image]

1. add a path curve
2. select the 2nd and 5th vertex and move them x(quantity) along the y-axis
3. select the 3th vertex and move it x/2 along the y-axis

you now have this curve:

[image]

you can also scale it along the x-axis to get a wider knot.

4. add a mirror modifier, and select the proper axis

you will now notice a issue, the top of the knot is not rounded but sharp.
To solve this:
-select 1st and second vertex, and subdivide once

- move the newly created vertex to the first vertex, and then move the newly created vertex along the y-axis until the top is smooth enough.
- repeat this process for last to vertecises too

you should now have something like this:
[image]

I will move the 3th and 4th vertex up by one so the knots fit in each other when we array them:
[image]

5. add an array modifier with relative y 1, and increase the count.
6. add another array modifier with relative x, and play a little with the value until it looks good, I will use 0.3
7. go under object data properties to geometry, under bevel increase depth to give the curve thickness.
   [image]

If you make them too ***THICK*** they will start drifting apart from each other, you can change the first array modifier from relative to constant to fix this, but you will have to play with the values.

if you want to use it for cloth simulation you will have to convert it to mesh, before you do that reduce the quality of the curve or you will get a few million vertices.
press <kbd>F3</kbd> and search for convert to, and it convert to mesh.

Final result:
[image]
sofa from [DimitraPe](https://skfb.ly/EGpQ)

Comment: Nice! I am definitely going to give this a try, though I'm not sure how well the polycount will work with my low end PC :)

Comment: @cgperfect It is indeed a lot, but i got through it with my patato laptop as well.

Answer (score 2):

My (updated) solution contains a cloth plane as this applies only to the material transparency pattern -- you would apply this to the cloth.   As you'll see, I used a fish-net pattern and I "spray painted the original fish-net image (only the "rope" parts show in the rendering).  I put some colored cubes behind the patterned cube.   I used the netting to also make the transmission mask and the alpha mask (inverted image for the alpha).
[image]

I include a link to this example [fabric.zip with blend and image files](http://optionpeer.com/jimtpersonal/fabric.zip)

Here is a capture with the cloth simulated over a blue object:
[image]

Comment: Good idea, I'll definitely be using this in the future, however I was looking for more of a knotted blanket type texture, instead of a fish net. Is there a way I could change the shape of it to more fit my blanket?

Comment: I gave you a general example.  The remainder is what we call "an exercise for the student".   I will go one step further, but you'll have to understand how to use an image that is specific and tailored and bespoke to your need.   For the following I:
searched google for images of wool, 
chose and copied the image from " [link](https://www.moodfabrics.com/gray-chunky-knit-printed-soft-rayon-woven-317532)",

Comment: used the image program GIMP to 
1) get B&W image of high contrast and save to _make.jpg, 
2) invert the image and save to _alpha.jpg  
3) spray the original gray wool red for a red wool (you might instead choose a better start image if you want to have multi-colored fabric) and saved to weave.jpg

Yes, it's a bit of effort that you'll want to invest in your project.
See updated example [here](http://www.optionpeer.com/jimtpersonal/wool_weave_cloth.zip)

Answer (score 0):

I gave you a general example. The remainder is what we call "an exercise for the student". I will go one step further, but you'll have to understand how to use an image that is specific and tailored and bespoke to your need. For the following I: searched google for images of wool, chose and copied the image from " [here](https://www.moodfabrics.com/gray-chunky-knit-printed-soft-rayon-woven-317532)", – james_t 5 mins ago

used the image program GIMP to 1) get B&W image of high contrast and save to _make.jpg, 2) invert the image and save to _alpha.jpg 3) spray the original gray wool red for a red wool (you might instead choose a better start image if you want to have multi-colored fabric) and saved to weave.jpg Yes, it's a bit of effort that you'll want to invest in your project. See updated example [here](http://www.optionpeer.com/jimtpersonal/wool_weave_cloth.zip)
[image]

Comment: instead of adding a new answer, edit your previous post, and update the text with further remarks. Add additional answers only if they are different solutions than the one you already posted.